# Is there any kind of iOS API that exists for detecting shapes through the camera?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been working with augmented reality API's lately but haven't been able to achieve irregular shape detection, namely the hand. I want to be able to detect hand shapes through the video/camera and execute code based on hand signs. Does anything like this already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)?

These are some of the links I found just using Google: [Face Detection using OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection), [Vision For Robots](http://www.iheartrobotics.com/search/label/Vision%20for%20Robots)

Comment: after thinking up some more search phrases, I just stumbled upon OpenCV. That's about the closet solution I've been able to find.